# CloudKit subscription error: Metasync subscriptions are not allowed in public database

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Getting this error attempting to subscribe to public database changes:

> CKError: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some
>   subscriptions"; uuid = ...; container ID = "..."; partial errors: {
>     allpublic-changes = CKError: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2006); server
>   message = "Metasync subscriptions are not allowed in public database"

```
let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "allpublic-changes")

let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: [])
    operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { [weak self] (savedSubscriptions:[CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs:[String]?, error:Error?) in

        guard error == nil else{

            print("modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock error: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        ...
    }

operation.qualityOfService = .utility
CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```

A google search yields no results for this error message whatsoever. Anyone else encountered this?

iOS 10, on device.

**Edit**:
deleted some characters that were preventing the whole error message to be shown.

If I do the same on the private DB, no issues.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: I didn't, I took another approach in the end (been a while, can't remember), but I gave up on cloud kit, firebase is much easier and better.

Comment: I just asked a question on Apple dev forum an I got this reply: "CKDatabaseSubscriptions aren't supported in the public database, as the error indicates.  For the public database you would need to use a CKQuerySubscription instead," check [the question here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76851)

Comment: @MEnnabah Yeah, that's why I took another approach. The wording ("Metasync"?) threw me off initially though. It's kind of sad though that you can't subscribe to public database changes, it's either bad design or Apple couldn't care less about CloudKit.

Comment: So the CKQuerySubscription won't give me the same result like subscribing to changes in the public database?

Comment: @MEnnabah they're not the same thing. A database subscription will fire whenever any change happens inside a database. With query subscription you're subscribing specifically to something, but your app can't subscribe to something (a new structure of data for instance) that wasn't there before the release.

Comment: Ahh okey got it. thanks for the hint

Comment: According to this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-231/?time=454 ...`CKDatabaseSubscriptions` **are** allowed on public databases. That said, I'm getting this same error: `Metasync subscriptions are not allowed in public database` when I try to set one up. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

CKDatabaseSubscriptions aren't supported in the public database, as the error indicates.  For the public database you would need to use a CKQuerySubscription instead